# Erro ao carregar mailparse no servidor, mas meu sistema não usa mailparse

Tags: php

Fiz um pequeno sistema de cadastro usando PHP e MySQL, funcionou direitinho no servidor local mas na hora de subir para o servidor acontece o seguinte:

Há um arquivo chamado `view.php` na raiz, esse arquivo é deletado do nada e quando tento acessar recebo um erro 500 (Estranhamente, não um 404, já que ele foi deletado), também é gerado um error_log em outra pasta(core/login/security.php).

```
[09-Dec-2014 19:02:39 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mailparse.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mailparse.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[09-Dec-2014 19:02:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mailparse.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mailparse.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[09-Dec-2014 19:02:53 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mailparse.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mailparse.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[09-Dec-2014 19:03:43 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mailparse.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mailparse.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

O estranho é que meu sistema nada tem a ver com o mailparse (Segundo a definição do PHP.net)
Alguém tem alguma ideia do que possa estar causando o problema?

Comment: Grandes chances de seu servidor ter sido invadido e infectado com alguma coisa que faz uso da mailparse para enviar dados para o atacante.

Comment: Se o servidor for seu comentar(no php.ini) ou desinstalar essa extensão, caso seja uma hospedagem entre contato com eles.